# Ansible: XML module to read an attribute value and access it

Tags: python, xml, linux, ansible

I am using Ansible playbook to extract a specific attribute value from an XML file, as prescribed in [the Ansible XML module page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html), but getting an error "Xpath /business/website/validxhtml does not reference a node".

XML file:

```
<business type="bar">
  <name>Tasty Beverage Co.</name>
    <beers>
      <beer>Rochefort 10</beer>
      <beer>St. Bernardus Abbot 12</beer>
      <beer>Schlitz</beer>
    </beers>
  <rating subjective="true">10</rating>
  <website>
    <mobilefriendly/>
    <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
  </website>
</business>
```

YAML file:

```
- name: Read an element's attribute values
  xml:
    path: /home/ansible/test.xml
    xpath: /business/website/validxhtml
    content: attribute
  register: xmlresp

- name: Show an attribute value
  debug:
    var: xmlresp.matches[0].validxhtml.validatedon
```

Response:

```
PLAY [testing XMl values] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Read an element's attribute values] ********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Xpath /business/website/validxhtml does not reference a node!"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am using same example as specified in Ansible xml page, but not sure why it's failing..Please help.

Comment: Your XPath is `/business/website/validxhtml`, your XML file does not contain a `<validxhtml>` element, you get the error *"Xpath does not reference a node"*... that's a pretty straightforward error.

Comment: The example given on that webpage adds those elements to the file prior to the task you have here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because neither `validxhtml` element exist nor `attribute` in sample xml. First of all XML like HTML has Elements & Attributes, both are different things [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp)

So you need to either add `validxhtml` element with attribute & value you want to extract or use other element which has attribute e.g `<rating subjective="true">10</rating>` in xml file. I hope that helps.

[**UPDATE**]
As requested if you want to get only element value just try this it should return `10`.

```
- name: Read an element's attribute values
  xml:
    path: /home/ansible/test.xml
    xpath: /business/rating
    content: text
  register: xmlresp

- name: Show an attribute value
  debug:
    var: xmlresp.matches
```

Comment: Hi, please help me understand more, i have tried changing         xpath: /business/rating & var: xmlresp.matches[0].rating.validatedon.. ( to extract value "10" from rating - for example), but i am getting Ok response with VARIABLE NOT DEFINED.

Comment: my intention is to extract specific attribute from XML file, either value "10" from rating, or may be string "http://tastybeverageco.com" which is under website/address.

Comment: Value `10` & `tastybeverageco.com` are element values. So to get element value you just have to specify `content: text` along with xpath.

Comment: thanks a lot...Got required value when i use xmlresp.matches i.e., value "10".